# Flask / React / Heroku app cannot find bundle.js

Tags: python, reactjs, heroku, flask, flask-restful

I'm creating an app with flask on the backend and React on the front end and I'm trying to host it on Heroku. Heroku deploys the app fine, but it cannot find /static/bundle.js.

My directory structure is:

```
.
+-- app.py
+-- js
|   +-- app.js (React)
+-- static
|   +-- bundle.js
+-- nodemodules
+-- package.json
+-- Procfile
+-- requirements.txt
+-- templates
|   + index.html
+-- venv
+-- webpack.config.js
```

My app.py file serves index.html fine with

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

index.html tries to serve bundle.js (I've tried both url_for and relative path)

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="reactEntry"></div>

  <!-- Attach React components -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bundle.js') }}"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

The error I get is

```
GET https://dark-temple-505050.herokuapp.com/static/bundle.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Anyone know how to properly serve the bundle?